# Can outlook preview activate a XLS malware?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, virus, malware, microsoft-outlook-2016

If I get a suspicious XLS file attachment, and accidentally view the file in the PREVIEW pane, will the malware code be executed ?

This is for the *latest version* of Outlook 2016, standard setup with all updates installed, connected to a microsoft online account. Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

I found something about this [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-Outlook-helps-protect-you-from-viruses-spam-and-phishing-7edf2cc7-2e7e-4897-86d9-0bd306dde60d). I know this is about Office 2007 but I'm sure this also goes for Office 2016

> Previewing and opening messages safely
>
> Office Outlook 2007 uses only one editor, based on Microsoft Office
>   Word 2007, for you to compose and read e-mail messages by opening the
>   messages or by previewing them in the Reading Pane. Scripts, macros,
>   and ActiveX controls cannot run in any message format, whether you use
>   plain text, HTML, or Rich Text Format (RTF). However, SmartTags are
>   allowed to run, as are custom forms.
>
> If you prefer, you always have the option of reading messages in plain
>   text, even though that does not provide full protection against all
>   e-mail hazards.

And for the Macro's this is already disabled by default in Office 2016.

> The purpose of a macro is to automate frequently used tasks. Although
>   some macros are simply a recording of your keystrokes or mouse clicks,
>   more powerful VBA macros are authored by developers who use code that
>   can run many commands on your computer. For this reason, VBA macros
>   pose a potential security risk because a hacker can introduce a
>   malicious macro through a document that, if opened, allows the macro
>   to run and potentially spread a virus on your computer.
>
> In 2007 Office release, the Trust Center helps to provide protection
>   against potentially unsafe macros. In addition, Outlook blocks
>   potentially unsafe attachments.